# Test REST API from local server in ionic real android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have a MongoDB server running locally on my laptop.
In my app I'm making HTTP get requests to the server with localhost:server_port.
Both my laptop and my phone are connected to the same WiFi.
When I'm testing my app with ionic serve I get a response when I make the requests. However, on my android phone it doesn't work.

I know there are a few possible solutions for this but I've tried them all with no success.

Comment: are you using express api that you built ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your phone is connected to the same network as your computer. In your ionic app where you're making API calls, change it from `localhost` to the private IP address (192.168... likely) of your computer. It's because your computer can understand `localhost` (because of configuration in the host file), but the phone you're testing does not know what `localhost` is (It cannot translate it to IP address). Therefore, you have to provide literal IP address.

If that does not work, enable CORS in your API. This is how you do it in express.

```
npm install --save cors

var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: did you change from localhost to ipaddress and confirm that  both are on the same network ?

Comment: Glad to help. :) Check updated answer for explanation. @kitsuneFox